# Activity Feed/Deleted Items "Record not found" crashing Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have an activity feed in a Rails 3 app and it updates whenever someone adds a comment or posts something. The feed is clickable and takes the user to the item. However, if the item is deleted, the link that remains on the feed is now "dead" and it crashes the app when the page (the one containing the feed) is loaded.

How can I have the dead link redirect to a "this item has been deleted" page instead of linking to the dead item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the ItemsController:

```
def show
  @item = Item.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path, :alert => "This item has been removed."
end
```

Comment: Note that the item does not necessarily need to be deleted in this case. The user could also manipulate the ID in the URL, so the message should say something like "could not be found or was deleted"